# Is there a way to avoid untyped ActorRef in scala cookbook actor communication example?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In *scala cookbook: 13.3. How to Communicate Between Actors* I see this

```
class Ping(pong: ActorRef) extends Actor { // OMG - ActorRef - no type, help!
  var count = 0
  def incrementAndPrint { count += 1; println("ping") }
  def receive = {
    case StartMessage =>
      incrementAndPrint
```

I have got also a few places in my own code where I have this `ActorRef` I don't like it as I liked `type safety`.  Is there a way to avoid that in the above `pong` example?

*Side Note: I understand I can use "actorFor" with naming, but as a **DI** freak I rather pass it in constructor / parameter.*

Comment: In short it's very hard to implement. During the first reactive course on coursera there was a discussion on forum about type safety of Akka. In general there are ways to do this locally, e.g Dr. Roland Kuhn was working on type channels to bring some safety, but the research result weren't very satisfying and they were removed from Akka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some stuff is in the works for Akka 3.0 eg see this teaser thread: https://mobile.twitter.com/RayRoestenburg/status/510511346040197120

There is a pattern for type safety now using a custom ask (the question mark).  Here is a blog about it:
http://www.warski.org/blog/2013/05/typed-ask-for-akka/

This is a little clunky though and may not be worth the trouble.

Another approach is to create typed APIs and wrap your actors in them.